# keyboard can not disappear, textfield in a cell of table

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

what I am trying to do is to fill the info into the cell of my table and a cell is loaded from the nib file which contains UILabel and UITextField like below

[image]

After feeding info to the table view, I am having

[image]

A keyboard will pop up whenever I click on the text field. However, if I click any areas which not belongs to text field, the keyboard wont disappear after all.

I implemented one of the delegates of UITextFieldDelegate like below

```
-(void) touchesBegan :(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [firstName resignFirstResponder];
    [lastName resignFirstResponder];
    [email1 resignFirstResponder];
    [email2 resignFirstResponder];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event ];
}
```

**My question is** : how can I make a keyboard disappear.

Please advice me on this issue. Any comments are welcomed here.

Thanks

Comment: Hint : `resignFirstResponder`

Comment: I have just updated my OP,please take a look again. sorry not give you a full detail of **touchesBegan:withEvent**

Comment: Please post your cellforrowarindexpath method

Comment: Ha, you didn't mention there is UITableView before. UITableView will absorb the touch events, so you have to use `resignFirstResponder` in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this done by following:
 Declare a property for another textfield say currField; 
   whenever you touch anywhere, resign your keyboard inside touch delegate methods.

Let me know if you still face any problem.

Tarun

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    [txt_1 resignFirstResponder];
    [txt_2 resignFirstResponder];
    // add more if needed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in which class you are handling the touch event? You can handle the touch events in you custom cell class. There you just have to call the resignFirstResponder for the singleTextField associated with that cell.